# AWS data storage: how much to store with Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-lambda

I am new here.

This is rather a choice-based question rather than purely technical one.

Many mobile apps authenticate with **Cognito**, and I am going to use the same for ease of use + free tier advantage.

However, to enable some functionality, I must also store some user data on AWS RDS (postgres). I am wondering about my choice though:

- I am relatively unaware of all complexities of custom user authentication (I have successfully implemented using Cognito already), and am wondering if I am losing a lot by going for quick and easy Cognito solution?
- There will obviously be some duplication of data fields between both Cognito and RDS. User UUID or email. Is this normal? How successful apps usually handle it?
- Is backup from Cognito cost-effective? For example, how much it could cost if I have a [lambda to back up](https://github.com/rahulpsd18/cognito-backup-restore) my 100K users from Cognito?
- What is cost effective in the long run? Having everything in Cognito or my own RDS database?
- Is migration even possible (from Cognito to my RDS) - as it totally depends upon clients wanting to upgrade the app?
- **MOST IMPORTANT:** In general, how does the data sync between Cognito and RDS happen? Is there a popular approach I am missing out?

If I am supposed to use a pre-built identity provider, I have already made up my choice about using Cognito (since my other stuff is already on AWS) - so I am **not keen on considering Auth0 at least at this point** - just to narrow down my choice.